# Extend an object from ViewData in MVC HtmlHelpers

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am building an ajax form using the MVC Ajax Helpers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505013.aspx

The code looks similar to:

```
Ajax.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName",
    new {
            SomeProperty = (ViewData["SomeObject"] as SomeClass).SomeProperty,
            AnotherProperty = (ViewData["SomeObject"] as SomeClass).AnotherProperty,
            AllTheProperties = (ViewData["SomeObject"] as SomeClass).AllTheProperties,
            otherProperty= ViewData["otherObject"]
        },
  new AjaxOptions {},
  new {id = "anHtmlId"} );
```

but there are plenty of more properties in `ViewData["SomeObject"]` though.

I would like to add `ViewData["otherObject"]` to the routeData object simply with as few lines as possible and do not want have all of the properties of `someObject` laid out individually so that I can add properties to it without having to revisit this code in the view.

Essentially "merging" these objects to pass as the routeData parameter would be useful.

---

**Update:** an idea:

```
Ajax.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName",
    ViewData["SomeObject"].addThePropertiesOf(ViewData["otherObject"]),
  new AjaxOptions {},
  new {id = "anHtmlId"} );
```

Where `addThePropertiesOf()` returns a new merged object. I wouldn't like to use the expensive bits of reflection otherwise this doesn't seem performant.

Comment: Sounds vaguely like something AutoMapper might do.

Comment: Automapper seems like a sledgehammer on a nail for something used rendering a view.

Comment: On one hand, yes, on the other hand maybe `otherObject` is a property of `someObject` and you just want to use an existing library to flatten the thing and take the properties you don't want from `someObject` out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's the point of sending some values to the HTML which cannot be modified by the user as they are not part of the form as input elements just to resend them back on postback as query string parameters? Makes no sense. It's a total waste of bandwidth. For me all you need to send to the server when you post this form is some unique identifier (in addition of course to all the form fields that the user can modify):

```
Ajax.BeginForm(
    "ActionName", 
    "ControllerName", 
    new { id = (ViewData["SomeObject"] as SomeClass).Id }, 
    new AjaxOptions { }, 
    new { id = "anHtmlId"} 
)
{
    ... some input fields that the user can modify and
        that will automatically be sent to the server when
        the form is submitted
}
```

And of course for all values that can be modified you will have corresponding input fields whose values would obviously be automatically posted to the server.

Finally on the server use this unique identifier to refetch the original values from wherever you fetched them in your GET action when you rendered the form. You fetched them from somewhere, right, otherwise you wouldn't have been able to store them in the `ViewData` in the first place.

And please get rid of those `ViewData/ViewBag`, define view models and use strongly typed views. I am starting to exhibit some real allergies towards those two weakly typed constructs that should never be used in any ASP.NET MVC application.

Comment: While it seems bad practice, there are plenty of good reasons for the points you've raised, keeping multiple states and RESTful requests for dynamic content without using session. I agree with you about objects being in the viewdata when models should be used.

Comment: @StuperUser, who said anything about session? All I said is to append an id and use this id to fetch the values from your datastore (/database or whatever). No session at all. I am a great enemy of any sessions in a web application. Totally agree with you that it is not RESTful to use sessions.

Comment: The way these data are used (some are Ids), storing/retrieving them from the disk each time, becomes an emulation of Session that uses the database to keep the state. `otherProperty` is often similar, so it may make sense to extend `SomeClass` to return an new object otherProperty and the rest of SomeClass.

Comment: @StuperUser, well then if you don't want to follow my advice about a RESTFul design you could take a look at the MVCContrib's `Html.Serialize` helper which serializes an entire object graph as a hidden field and you can fetch it back on the POST controller action as an action argument. So you can dump your entire ViewData inside a base64 serialized hidden field. By the way under the covers this helper uses the classic ASP.NET ViewState. Remember this? That's what you are trying to do. ViewState! In an ASP.NET MVC application! It's a blasphemy towards the MVC pattern.

Comment: I'm glad that your brilliant mind ran to ViewState too, it's all I could do to not throw up in my mouth when trying to solve this one too :)

Comment: As the apps get bigger, the statelessness of HTTP is going to have people recreating ViewStates for years to come :)

Comment: @StuperUser, not necessarily. Let's try to limit the damages. I know that there might be some situations in the real world which might require ViewState but if we can avoid them it would be great.